# Ocultar primeiros elementos por inteiro ate que não saia da div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Estou com um problema com o css, não sei como ocultar os primeiro elemento (já que está em `float: rigth`, ele fica ao contrario) por inteiro ate que caibam na div deixando de sair para fora.

```css
:root {
  --tema: #167c80;
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  outline: 0;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  height: 45px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  box-shadow: 1.5px 1.5px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  z-index: 4;
  transition: top .3s;
  background: #fff;
}

.header h1 {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: var(--tema);
  font-weight: 500;
  left: 5px;
  line-height: 42px;
  width: 90px;
  transition: linear .3s all;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header .upload-slide {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: linear .3s all;
  border-bottom: solid 2.5px var(--tema);
}

.menu-ico {
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  left: -50px;
  transition: linear .3s all;
}

.menu-ico div {
  height: 3px;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background: var(--tema);
  margin: 4.5px 0px;
}

.header .botoes {
  position: absolute;
  right: 45px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: calc(100% - 158px);
}

.header .botoes label {
  width: fit-content;
  height: 45px;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  float: right;
  margin: 0px 7px;
  text-align: center;
  color: var(--tema);
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.header label[for=chk-perfil] {
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

.header label[for=chk-perfil] img {
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: solid transparent 5px;
}

.header .botoes label i {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 12px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: var(--tema);
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0.5px 0.5px 2.5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  padding: 3px;
  display: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.header .botoes label span {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.header .botoes label p {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 42px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.header .botoes .transfers {
  display: none;
}

.header .address_bar {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  max-width: calc(100% - 175px);
}

.header .address_bar a {
  height: 35px;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}

.header .address_bar a button.bar {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: fit-content;
  text-align: left;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  color: #222;
  border-bottom: solid 1.5px transparent;
  min-width: 25px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" />
<header class="header">
  <label class="menu-ico" for="chk-menu">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </label>
  <h1>Nuvem</h1>
  <!-- barra de upload-->
  <div class="upload-slide"></div>
  <!-- botao perfil -->
  <label for="chk-perfil">
        <img src="<?php echo $_SESSION['nc_data'][3]; ?>" />
    </label>
  <!-- botoes do explorer-->
  <div class="botoes for_explorer">
    <!-- Barra de endereco-->
    <div class="address_bar">
      <a>
        <button class="ion-chevron-left sub_address bar"></button>
        <button class="bar" value="">D:</button>
      </a>
      <a>
        <button class="ion-chevron-left sub_address bar"></button>
        <button class="bar" value="">Media</button>
      </a>
      <a>
        <button class="ion-chevron-left sub_address bar"></button>
        <button class="bar" value="">Musicas</button>
      </a>
      <a>
        <button class="bar" value="">NCS</button>
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-- botoes -->
    <label class="transfers" for="chk-copymove">
            <i></i>
            <span class="ion-android-clipboard"></span>
        </label>
    <label class="uploads" for="chk-upload">
            <p></p>
            <i></i>
            <span class="ion-upload"></span>
        </label>
    <label class="folder">
            <span class="ion-android-folder-open"></span>
        </label>
    <label class="list" for="chk-itens">
            <span class="ion-navicon"></span>
        </label>
    <label class="back">
            <span class="ion-arrow-left-b"></span>
        </label>
  </div>
</header>
```

como está, e como eu gostaria que ficasse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Cara acho que até deu para entender o problema, mas sem o código completo não da para te ajudar muito, vc tem que colocar o código do menu e dos ícones da direita tb, sem eles só da pra tentar te responder no chute...

Comment: Ok, mas vai ficar um pouco grande.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue uma alternativa

Primeiro tire o `float-right` dos A e coloque no HTML a ordem correta, começando pelo NSC. Depois tire `width 100%` da `address_bar` e coloque `overflow: hidden;`. E agora cloque `display:flex` na div `.botoes` e alinhe os itens no final do *container* com `justify-content: flex-end;`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
        :root {
            --tema: #167c80;
        }

        * {
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
            -webkit-touch-callout: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -khtml-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
            outline: 0;
        }

        .header {
            position: fixed;
            height: 45px;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            box-shadow: 1.5px 1.5px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
            z-index: 4;
            transition: top .3s;
            background: #fff;
        }

        .header h1 {
            position: absolute;
            margin: 0;
            height: 100%;
            font-size: 25px;
            color: var(--tema);
            font-weight: 500;
            left: 5px;
            line-height: 42px;
            width: 90px;
            transition: linear .3s all;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .header .upload-slide {
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            top: 0;
            opacity: 0;
            width: 0%;
            height: 100%;
            transition: linear .3s all;
            border-bottom: solid 2.5px var(--tema);
        }

        .menu-ico {
            width: 45px;
            height: 45px;
            position: absolute;
            padding: 3px 5px;
            cursor: pointer;
            left: -50px;
            transition: linear .3s all;
        }

        .menu-ico div {
            height: 3px;
            float: left;
            width: 100%;
            background: var(--tema);
            margin: 4.5px 0px;
        }

        .header .botoes {
            position: absolute;
            right: 45px;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            max-width: calc(100% - 158px);
            display: flex;
            justify-content: flex-end;
        }

        .header .botoes label {
            width: fit-content;
            height: 45px;
            font-size: 30px;
            padding: 5px 0px;
            float: right;
            margin: 0px 7px;
            text-align: center;
            color: var(--tema);
            cursor: pointer;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
        }

        .header label[for=chk-perfil] {
            width: 45px;
            height: 45px;
            font-size: 35px;
            color: #fff;
            cursor: pointer;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
        }

        .header label[for=chk-perfil] img {
            object-fit: cover;
            height: 45px;
            width: 45px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            border: solid transparent 5px;
        }

        .header .botoes label i {
            position: absolute;
            font-size: 12px;
            bottom: 0px;
            right: 0;
            margin: 5px;
            height: 20px;
            width: 20px;
            background: var(--tema);
            border-radius: 50%;
            box-shadow: 0.5px 0.5px 2.5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
            padding: 3px;
            display: none;
            color: #fff;
        }

        .header .botoes label span {
            float: left;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .header .botoes label p {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            position: absolute;
            margin: 0px;
            font-size: 20px;
            line-height: 42px;
            opacity: 0;
        }

        .header .botoes .transfers {
            display: none;
        }

        .header .address_bar {
            float: left;
            /* width: 100%; */
            height: 100%;
            padding: 5px 0px;
            max-width: calc(100% - 175px);
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .header .address_bar a {
            height: 35px;
            /* float: right; */
            position: relative;
        }

        .header .address_bar a button.bar {
            height: 100%;
            position: relative;
            float: left;
            width: fit-content;
            text-align: left;
            border: none;
            background: transparent;
            color: #222;
            border-bottom: solid 1.5px transparent;
            min-width: 25px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" />
    <header class="header">
        <label class="menu-ico" for="chk-menu">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </label>
        <h1>Nuvem</h1>
        <!-- barra de upload-->
        <div class="upload-slide"></div>
        <!-- botao perfil -->
        <label for="chk-perfil">
            <img src="<?php echo $_SESSION['nc_data'][3]; ?>" />
        </label>
        <!-- botoes do explorer-->
        <div class="botoes for_explorer">
            <!-- Barra de endereco-->
            <div class="address_bar">
                <a>
                    <button class="bar" value="">NCS</button>
                </a>
                <a>
                    <button class="ion-chevron-left sub_address bar"></button>
                    <button class="bar" value="">Musicas</button>
                </a>
                <a>
                    <button class="ion-chevron-left sub_address bar"></button>
                    <button class="bar" value="">Media</button>
                </a>
                <a>
                    <button class="ion-chevron-left sub_address bar"></button>
                    <button class="bar" value="">D:</button>
                </a>
            </div>
            <!-- botoes -->
            <div>
                <label class="transfers" for="chk-copymove">
                    <i></i>
                    <span class="ion-android-clipboard"></span>
                </label>
                <label class="uploads" for="chk-upload">
                    <p></p>
                    <i></i>
                    <span class="ion-upload"></span>
                </label>
                <label class="folder">
                    <span class="ion-android-folder-open"></span>
                </label>
                <label class="list" for="chk-itens">
                    <span class="ion-navicon"></span>
                </label>
                <label class="back">
                    <span class="ion-arrow-left-b"></span>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

</body>

</html>
```